# Binding single control to different Datacontext in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button `button_extract`. I want to bind it to two different data contexts (2 classes in different namespaces)

I want to set the Command and `IsEnabled` properties to different data context.

I have one `datacontext` set for Command property. But how to I specify the `datacontext` of `IsEnable` property which is in different class and namespace. Here is the scenario:-

I have a project named Environments with three namespaces:Viewmodel,Data and View
Viewmodel has class A
Data has class B
View has xaml C with button button_extract.

The data context for C is set to class A.The xaml is as follows

```
<UserControl x:Class="Enviornment.Views.C"             
         DataContext="Environment.Viewmodel.A">

<Button Name="button_extract" Command="{Binding ExtractButtonClick}" IsEnabled="{Enviornment.B.SelectedEnvionment}" >Extract</Button>
```

The above code does not work. The binding of IsEnabled throws error. How can I set the datacontext of IsEnabled to that of Enviornment.B???

Comment: You can specify the full path for a Binding. Post your best attempt and the specific problems you are having with it.

Comment: By setting the "Path" part of the Binding. Post your best attempt so we canhelp you or read a good tutorial to find it out all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a common misconception about WPF regarding the need to set the `DataContext`. In fact, there is rarely any need to set a `DataContext` on any control as typically the `Window` has had its `DataContext` set and each control's `DataContext` will automatically inherit from that.

So, how to data bind to two different places? Generally, one place would use a normal `Binding Path` and the other would use a `RelativeSource Binding Path`. However, that would be more for the case where you wanted to data bind to properties of the set `DataContext` *and* properties of a control's code behind.

It is more common in your scenario to simply prepare a view model. That is a custom class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and provides *all of the properties and functionality* that your `Window`, `UserControl`, or 'view' requires. You would then set an instance of this single object as the `DataContext`.

Therefore, simply add properties of the relevant classes into your view model and then you will be able to access them all using the one single `DataContext` object. Please search online for MVVM for further information.